# Can I use redux just for event driven business logic?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have only seen redux being used hand in hand with React (or I suppose other popular frameworks) and each state change is related to a UI change. I was thinking if I could use redux totally separated from a React component to achieve event driven programming. But React gives me the `useEffect` hook to listen to variable changes.

So does `redux` provides an event listener out of the box ?
I want to keep the `useSelector` functionality to get the desired state variable, but then I want to replace `useEffect` with another event listener on this variable in order to perform some logic or dispatch another action. I don't need to render something, just to apply certain code depending on the state of the app. Can this be done only in redux environment ?

Comment: My perception of the concept is that all application state should be held by redux. Not only state that is reflected in the UI, even though that is the most common use case. Have no experience with React so cannot comment on the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally do that!

If you only want to listen for state changes, you can use `store.addListener`. If you want to observer actions and the according before/after state, you can write your own middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Redux provides a mechanism to subscribe to changes in the state that can be used outside of a UI framework like React. This is possible through the store.subscribe() method, which allows you to register a callback that will be executed any time the state has potentially changed.

```
    import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

// Function to select the part of the state you are interested in
const selectState = (state) => state.someParticularKey;

let currentState;

function handleChange() {
  // Check for the part of the state you care about
  let nextState = selectState(store.getState());

  // If that part of state has changed, do something about it
  if (nextState !== currentState) {
    currentState = nextState;
    // Perform logic or dispatch an action
    // ...
  }
}

// Subscribe to the store
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange);

// To unsubscribe from the updates at some point in the future
unsubscribe();
```

In the code above, the handleChange function acts as an event listener on the Redux state. It invokes selectState to get the current relevant slice of the state and checks whether it has changed since the last time it ran. If it has, you can run the appropriate logic or dispatch another action.

This subscription-based approach is reminiscent of how you might use useEffect in React to react to changes in your Redux state via useSelector. However, now you are managing it manually. It's important to remember that this approach lacks the optimizations provided by hooks like useSelector, so it requires careful attention to performance considerations, such as avoiding unnecessary work inside the handleChange callback or using memoization techniques where appropriate.

You should also ensure to clean up subscriptions when they are no longer needed to avoid memory leaks — just as you would with useEffect cleanup in a React component.